# Problems with getting the command from user input

Tags: java, command-line, command, java-stream, command-line-arguments

I am currently struggling with the Stream that gets the command that was entered.

It looks like this

```
final Command command = commands.stream()
        .filter(cmd -> (input.startsWith(cmd.getName()) && (input.length() == cmd.getName().length()
                || input.charAt(cmd.getName().length()) == ' ')))
        .findAny()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new InvalidInputException("unknown command"));
```

For example, getName() of my ExitCommand looks like this:

```
@Override
public String getName() {
    return "exit";
}
```

The stream works perfectly fine, except that it also accepts input like "exit ". So exit plus a space. That shouldn't happen and I am not sure how to fix that. It's quite complicated because there are commands that are one-, two- and three- word long. (For example "exit", "delete rolling stock", "list trains").

I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: I don’t know of any command shell which rejects commands just for having a trailing space. Such a policy would be surprising for most users. The correct behavior also depends on how you are processing the words afterwards, e.g., what happens when there are two spaces?

Answer (score 0):

If there is always some input, and the command is always the first word before a space or end of input, how about first doing something like `String inputCommand = input.split(" ")[0];` and then just look for that exact value in your collection of commands.

Comment: As I said, there are one- two- and three- word commands. Unfortunately, this won't work here.

Comment: Oh okay - I thought the command was just the first word and the rest was arguments

Comment: Can't you just use trim if it is space at the beginning or end that's the problem? Or if the problem is space anywhere you could split the input and then stream and collect using joining, with a space - that would put a space between each word. In short, I think it would be easier to clean the input first than try to do that while searching for a matching command.

Comment: The problem with the space is just at the end. How would I use trim() here? I've never used that method before.

Comment: Trim is super-easy - it's just a method on String - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim() but looking again at your question are you saying you want to reject input where there is a trailing space or are you trying to be lenient and accept it - your code looks like you are aiming to be lenient, which I think would make sense from a user experience perspective, but depends on your requirements

Comment: I want to reject input where there is a trailing space.

Comment: OK, I've fixed my problem. Thanks!